# Is Contract Deployment analogous to Object Instantiation?

Tags: contract-deployment

Is deploying a contract analogous to instantiating a plaint old class in OOP and the address returned similar to the memory pointer of the OOP object? Should I be thinking of the ledge as memory to a running program?

If yes, then if I’m looking to do have something like an array of objects then I would have another contract that creates a new contract and store it’s address in array field?

Answer (score 1):

Actually deploying a contract is not analogous to instantiating an object.

Deploying a contract is like publishing your program for the world to see/use. So when you deploy your contract you create a version of it and publish it. The difference is that regular programs are typically available at the same "address" with a new version but deploying the same contract (or its updated version) never uses the same address.

However you can instantiate a new contract from within an existing contract by doing something like `MyContract contr = new MyContract()` and this creates the contract and its address (and functionality) is accessible from the `contr` variable. Or you can simply create a reference to an existing contract with `MyContract contr = MyContract(address_of_contract)`. In both cases the `contr` variable is an instance of the contract and is therefore analogous to the OOP world's instantiation.

So, yes, if you create contract within a contract you can store those addresses within an array.

Comment: Analogies are always imperfect, but I would say that yes, deploying a contract is analogous to instantiating an object.

Comment: Thank you for the response Lauri. Perhaps this depends on some items (allow me to expand). 
If I use remix and I want to create a modifier that checks on owner, then setting the owner is done in the constructor. And the since the constructor is called once, I had assumed that this was done when the contract was first deployed. I suppose using other than remix, deploying a contract would be done in a different way and then calling the constructor passing the address of the account owner would be the way the contract is instantiated.

Comment: Your opening statement and the explanation which follows it are confusing. The explanation does not imply that "deploying a contract is not analogous to instantiating an object", it implies that "deploying a contract is not analogous to publishing a regular program".

Comment: Well, there is obviously no right answer to this. I expressed my opinion, you are free to add another answer with your own opinions. I also disagree with you @goodvibration about the irregularity - maybe we just interpret the text differently. Thanks for the comments nevertheless :)

Comment: I did not suggest that your answer was wrong in any way. I just said that the explanation to the opening statement doesn't imply this statement, but something else.